# C#, reading one key value and other key value as value of a Dictionary to List<string,string>

Tags: c#

I have one dictionary, which contain information of as asset(like id, created on etc,). And I want to extract id value as key and created value as value to LIST using LINQ. Below is example.

```
Dictionary[0]=
    id:001, description:Test, name:SomeName, createdOn:11-09-2015

Dictionary[1]=
    id:002, description:Test2, name:SomeName2, createdOn:17-09-2015
```

I need to read to `List<string,string>` as

```
001:11-09-2015

002:17-09-2015
```

Now I tried to read only one value as below,

```
public Hits[] hits { get; set; };
hits.SelectMany(v => v.Source.Where(s => s.Key == "ObjId")).Select(s => s.Value).ToList()
```

Class is here:

```
public class Hits
{     
    [DataMember(Name = "_source")]
    public Dictionary<string,string> Source { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me the way to achieve this?

Comment: Very unclear. I guess you want a `Dictionary<string,List<CustomType>>` but you have neither shown your class(es) nor what `searchResult.srResponse.Hits` or `searchResult.srResponse.Hits.Hit` is.

Comment: @Tim, Is it clear now?

Comment: it seems you want as result a `List<string, string>`, which... does not exist. You can have a `List<whatever>` or a `Dictionary<whatever1, whatever2>`
Still not clear

Comment: Basically I will have multiple Hits(public Hits[] Hits { get; set; }), so multiple Dictionary. From this I need List<string, string> where values will be from value of different Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a List. List's have a single type. If you want a list of multiple types create a class to hold those types or use a Tuple

For your Linq you already have items in a dictionary, so there's no point doing the look up where key equals, just read the value from the dictionary.

The following should produce a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` containing the id and the createdOn field.  Which seemed to be what you wanted.

```
hits.Select(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x.Source["id"], x.Source["createdOn"])).ToList();
```

Alternatively you could have

```
List<string> = hits.Select(x => string.Format("{0}:{1}", x.Source["id"], x.Source["createdOn"])).ToList();
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, string> = hits.ToDictionary(x => x.Source["id"], x => x.Source["createdOn"]));
```